# Probability of a sum of two die rolls being 5 and not 7 in a game

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, transition-matrix

I've been working on this problem for a while and I'm not sure how to approach it. This was given in a class on Stochastic Processes, and it's meant to be solved using a Markov chain:

A single die is rolled repeatedly. The game stops the first time that the sum of two successive rolls is either 5 or 7. What is the probability that the game stops at a sum of 5?

What's the correct way to tackle this problem?

Comment: @angryavian yes I did try that, and I got a rather nasty system of equations that I'd rather not solve by hand (since these are problems that apparently shouldn't require any extremely tedious brute-force computations). I'm trying to reduce the dimensions of my transition matrix, and that's why I use this particular state space.

Comment: How nasty can the system be?  There are only $6$ states (not counting Start and Stop states).

Comment: I don't understand either your post or your comment.  This is obviously a Markov process, if we haven't stopped, all we care about is the last roll.  And the system can't possibly be complicated, there are too few states.

Comment: perhaps I should reclarify my question then: are there any ways of solving this problem that would use a system of equations of size less than 6 to solve? As for Henry's response, I was under the impression that if we were to transition from $\leq 4$ to $\geq 4$, then we would have to condition on what value our die roll was in the state $\leq 4$, since it can also end up being absorbed into $7$

Comment: That's an entirely arbitrary restriction.  Why not just solve the (rather straight forward) system of equations that the problem naturally represents?

Comment: @lulu: I think you need at least three "active states" as probabilities of movements between them is affected by their values

Comment: @Henry  I agree.  I already deleted my (incorrect) comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can obviously do this with nine states: the start, six transitional states depending on the previous roll, and the two end states. You can reduce these to six states:

- start
- previous roll 1 or 2 but not stopped yet
- previous roll 3 or 4 but not stopped yet
- previous roll 5 or 6 but not stopped yet
- stopped at sum of 5
- stopped at sum of 7

and a transition matrix of

\begin{pmatrix}
0 & \frac26 & \frac26 & \frac26 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \frac26 & \frac16 & \frac16 & \frac16 & \frac16 \\
0 & \frac16 & \frac16 & \frac26 & \frac16 & \frac16 \\
0 & \frac16 & \frac26 & \frac26 & 0 & \frac16 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}

Comment: Can you explain how you're calculating the probabilities in the transition matrix?  I don't understand how you're getting any of these.

Comment: @OliverG Take for example the fourth row ("previous roll 5 or 6 but not stopped yet").  There is a $0$ probability you return to the start, a $\frac16$ probability you roll 1 or 2 but not to get a pair sum of 7, a $\frac26$ probability you roll a 3 or 4 (the pair sum will be in 8,9,10),  a $\frac26$ probability you roll a 5 or 6 (the pair sum will be in 10,11,12), a $0$ probability you stop with a pair sum of 5, and a $\frac16$ probability  you stop with a pair sum of 7 (after rolling a 2 or 1 as needed).

Comment: Can you explain specifically how you're calculating the probabilities?  How did you calculate $p = P(X_{n+1} = 1 \text{ or } 2 | X_n = 5 \text{ or } 6 ) = \frac{1}{6}$ It seems to me that $p = P( (5,1) \text{ or } (6,2)) = \frac{2}{6}$.

Comment: @OliverG if you just rolled 5 but did not stop then the probability you roll a 1 next is $\frac16$ (rolling a 2 would lead to a stop); if you just rolled 6 but did not stop then the probability you roll a 2 next is also  $\frac16$ (rolling a 1 would lead to a stop).  So conditioned on your previous roll being either 5 or 6 but not stopped yet, then the probability of rolling 1 or 2 but not stopping is again $\frac16$